# How to identify all columns that have different values in a Spark self-join

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, diff, self-join, delta-lake

I have a Databricks delta table of financial transactions that is essentially a running log of all changes that ever took place on each record. Each record is uniquely identified by 3 keys. So given that uniqueness, each record can have multiple instances in this table. Each representing a historical entry of a change(across one or more columns of that record) Now if I wanted to find out cases where a specific column value changed I can easily achieve that by doing something like this -->

```sql
SELECT t1.Key1, t1.Key2, t1.Key3, t1.Col12 as "Before", t2.Col12 as "After" 
from table1 t1 inner join table t2 on t1.Key1= t2.Key1 and t1.Key2 = t2.Key2 
and t1.Key3 = t2.Key3 where t1.Col12 != t2.Col12
```

However, these tables have a large amount of columns. What I'm trying to achieve is a way to identify any columns that changed in a self-join like this. Essentially a list of all columns that changed. I don't care about the actual value that changed. Just a list of column names that changed across all records. Doesn't even have to be per row. But the 3 keys will always be excluded, since they uniquely define a record.

Essentially I'm trying to find any columns that are susceptible to change. So that I can focus on them dedicatedly for some other purpose.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Databricks has change data feed (CDF / CDC) functionality that can simplify these type of use cases. https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-change-data-feed.html